# Completely disable automatic incrementing of section and subsection counters?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, counters

I'm using LaTeX as a final build step from a specific legal source (a code of laws) that already has numbering - which is not entirely logical. So, the auto-stepping section & subsection numbering does not match the numbering of the laws and really cannot do so programmatically.

So, I would love to completely disable LaTeX/XeTeX's 'counter' system and specify explicitly every single section & subsection number. Is this possible?

Update: currently using the 'article' document class, and here's [a chunk of what I'm working on](https://gist.github.com/tmcw/5420843) (with non-functional calls to `\setcounter`)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which document class do you use?

Comment: Currently using article, here's the start of the doc:  https://gist.github.com/tmcw/5420843

Comment: erh, `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-10}` to disable numbering completely?

Comment: @daleif -- I think what the OP wants is to set the sectioning-related counters directly, rather than to disable numbering entirely. However, I may be wrong.

Comment: @mico To me it sounded more like the numbers was added as a part of the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code -- to be inserted in your document's preamble -- disables the stepping of all sectioning-related counters (not just the section and subsection counters). It is up to you, then, to provide your own counter-setting directives.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter  % remove the \refstepcounter directive from \@sect macro
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\refstepcounter{#1}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

*Addendum*: I just had a chance to look at the code you posted on github. A quick remark: You can't set "1-135" as the value of a counter variable; it has to be an integer. If you need to have the subsection "number" appear as "1-135" (where, presumably, `1` is the section number), you should issue the command

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection-\arabic{subsection}}
```

in the preamble and then simply set the `subsection` counter to `135` before invoking the `\subsection` command.

Comment: Can subsections have decimals? If one wanted a section like `29A` or a subsection like `30.32`, that's not possible?

Comment: @tmcw - would `30.32` be the "number" of a subsection or of a subsubsection (where `30` would be a subsection number)? Please advise.

Comment: 30.32 would be the number of a section: for instance, sections can go like '30, 30.1, 30.2, 31' in which 30.1 are siblings, not children, of 31. It's an odd system, but unfortunately not mine to change.

Comment: @tmcw - Thanks for clarifying this issue. Given the very much "free-format" nature of section and subsection numbers, I'd say it's probably easiest to use "unnumbered" sectioning commands -- `\section*`, `\subsection*`, etc -- and to supply the desired sectioning number as part of the argument of the sectioning command. E.g., you might write `\section*{30.32\quad <Title of section>}`.